# Upgrading laptop's RAM

Tags: memory

I have ASUS K55LN laptop with 6GB of ram and I want to upgrade it to 8GB+. So I unscrewed the bottom and found this RAM chip:

[image]

Beneath there are a few solded 4 small chips so I tought that they are integrated RAM. I tried to run laptop without this chip which was 2GB and when I entered OS it showed 4GB of RAM so as it seems there really is 4GB of integrated RAM because on the other side of Mobo there's no ram chips (1st time for me to even know that integrated RAM exists).

Now, which type is this RAM? I know it's 1600Hz but I don't know which latency to buy and PIN type and other things. Will be compatible with this integrated RAM already in?

Thanks!

Comment: The [ASUS K55LN](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K551LN/specifications/) uses `DDR3L 1600(O.C.) MHz` memory.  What is your question exactly?  DDR3 memory is DDR3 memory, the frequency of the memory in the screenshot, is indicated on the label.

Comment: all DDR3L's are equal? Will be compatible? What about CL? Voltage?

Comment: The module you have is a Low Voltage DDR3 memory hence DDR3L.  So provided you get DDR3L that is the same frequency it will work.  [The specific module in the screenshot is 1.35V](https://www.skhynix.com/products.view.do?vseq=955&cseq=75)

Comment: thx! you're cool

Comment: hmmm, I've lifted a little bit motherboard an nothing was beneath it. There are even some chips solded under RAM chip as I've already said

Comment: You asked what the module was its a low voltage DDR3 module.  Your follow up question isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

The memory module you have is a 2 GB DDR3L PC3L-12800 SODIMM. CL - 11

Check the below link for the 4 GB. You can refer it to buy from a source of your choice.
http://www.memorystock.com/orderitem.asp?it=895ms-895

And yes it will be compatible with the existing 4 GB. 
The existing 4 GB will be of the same size, it either will be in a closed cover box on the board. Some variants will have one module under the keyboard. That being said, its of the same size, so it should be under the keyboard, or under the laptop.

Comment: so it's not "integrated" as it seems? Maybe some day, I'll dissasamble the whole laptop to see that's between motherboard and keyboard